# Loops commutativity implies homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In my notes I have a theorem that says that if you have four path $\omega,\omega',\gamma\gamma'$ where $\omega\simeq\omega'$, $\gamma\simeq \gamma'$ and $\omega(1)=\omega'(1)=\gamma(0)=\gamma'(0)$ then $\omega\gamma\simeq\omega'\gamma'$.
Does the opposite applies to an abelian space?
I want to show that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two loops such as $\alpha\beta\simeq \beta\alpha$ then $\alpha\simeq \beta$

Comment: I'm not sure in what way your second statement is the opposite of your first, so there may be a typo? As stated, though, what you want is not true. For instance take a path that winds twice around the circle $S^1$ and a path that winds around three times. These two paths commute, but are not homotopic. Indeed as stated the claim is that every abelian fundamental group is trivial (which is clearly not true).

Comment: There's no typo. I'm just trying to understand how things work.

Apparently I failed miserably :s

Comment: Algebraic topology is famously hard. Don't beat yourself up for struggling with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider $\alpha$ a loop around $S^1$ and $\beta=\alpha^{-1}$ the reversed loop. Note that $\alpha\alpha^{-1}$ and $\alpha^{-1}\alpha$ are both homotopic to the constant loop but $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ are not homotopic (they correspond to $1$ and $-1$ under $\pi_1(S^1)=\langle[\alpha]\rangle \cong \mathbb Z$).

Indeed any two based loops in $S^1$ commute, as $\mathbb Z$ is abelian, but $\mathbb Z$ isn't trivial.